# Create a ssh_jenkins_slave image with JDK12 support

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-agent

I'm trying to create a custom ssh_slave_plugin docker template with support for JDK12. I've took the reference of the current ssh_jenkins_slave Dockerfile (https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-ssh-slave/blob/master/Dockerfile). However I'm not able to make it work and jenkins is not able to start the Jenkins agent.

The context is the following: Running Jenkins 2.176.2 and configured the Docker cloud with no issues (it can connect to the docker engine to spin off Docker templates as jenkins slaves).
When using the ssh_jenkins_slave default image, I can run it with no issues. I took the image and updated the JDK version to 12:

```
FROM openjdk:12-jdk

ARG user=jenkins
ARG group=jenkins
ARG uid=1000
ARG gid=1000
ARG JENKINS_AGENT_HOME=/home/${user}

ENV JENKINS_AGENT_HOME ${JENKINS_AGENT_HOME}

RUN groupadd -g ${gid} ${group} \
&& useradd -d "${JENKINS_AGENT_HOME}" -u "${uid}" -g "${gid}" -m -s /bin/bash "${user}"

# setup SSH server
RUN yum install -y openssh-server
RUN sed -i /etc/ssh/sshd_config \
        -e 's/#PermitRootLogin.*/PermitRootLogin no/' \
        -e 's/#RSAAuthentication.*/RSAAuthentication yes/'  \
        -e 's/#PasswordAuthentication.*/PasswordAuthentication no/' \
    -e 's/#SyslogFacility.*/SyslogFacility AUTH/' \
    -e 's/#LogLevel.*/LogLevel INFO/' && \
mkdir /var/run/sshd


#
# Install Sonar Scanner
#
ARG SONAR_SCANNER_VERSION=3.4.0.1729
ENV SONAR_SCANNER_HOME=/opt/sonar-scanner
ENV PATH $PATH:$SONAR_SCANNER_HOME/bin
RUN yum install -y unzip
RUN curl --insecure -o /tmp/sonarscanner.zip -L         https://binaries.sonarsource.com/Distribution/sonar-scanner-cli/sonar-scanner-cli-${SONAR_SCANNER_VERSION}.zip && \
unzip /tmp/sonarscanner.zip -d /opt && mv /opt/sonar-scanner-${SONAR_SCANNER_VERSION} /opt/sonar-scanner && \
rm /tmp/sonarscanner.zip && \
ln -s /opt/sonar-scanner/bin/sonar-scanner /usr/bin/sonar-scanner

VOLUME "${JENKINS_AGENT_HOME}" "/tmp" "/run" "/var/run"
WORKDIR "${JENKINS_AGENT_HOME}"

COPY setup-sshd /usr/local/bin/setup-sshd

EXPOSE 22

ENTRYPOINT ["setup-sshd"]
```

However, after I configure the Docker agent template and configure to start the docker image Connect with SSH (injecting SSH Key) I cannot use in my jenkins pipeline this image.

The error I see in jenkins is:

```
Reason: Template provisioning failed.
java.io.IOException: SSH service hadn't started after 20 seconds.    
at io.jenkins.docker.connector.DockerComputerSSHConnector.createLauncher(DockerComputerSSHConnector.java:261)
```

In my local machine, if I start a container with the image I can see the SSH server starting normally and I can log in without any issues.

Did anyone ever experienced this behavior? And tips on creating a Jenkins ssh_slave template with jdk 12?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I tried with the file that is the exact as yours, except it does not have Sonar part.
Have you included `setup-sshd` script file into your directory next to Dockerfile when building the image?
Have you set the executable permission on the `setup-sshd` file? That worked for me.

Comment: It was related to your tip. In the end was a problem of permissions - with the user UID of the machine not being the same of the container. But in the end you are right, it was a problem with permissions